# Gravatar alternative for Wordpress

Tags: plugins

I don't know whether it's something I'm doing wrong or an issue with the Gravatar website in general, but it doesn't seem to let me create an account (no error is given, the account just doesn't get created). There's no contact information that I could find for them to contact them.

Regardless, is there something that will provide the avatar functionality in a similar way that I can use (that works)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to contact Gravatar support](http://en.gravatar.com/site/faq/#answer-1-9)

There are also several options( [1](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-local-avatar/) ,  [2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-local-avatars/) ; just examples) for handling the avatars locally instead.